# Getting /dev/hidraw# via udev for script

Tags: udev

I have a small Python scriptlet that remaps my Logitech G710 G keys from the default of 1-6 to F13-18, which works fine when called manually, for example:

`./script.py /dev/hidraw3`

The issue I'm having is autorunning the script on device plugin. Currently I have a [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rule that theoretically should work, but it does not.

`SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c24d", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/g710.py %k"`

The whole script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import hid

def bindkeys(node):
    board = hid.device()
    board.open_path(sys.argv[1].encode())
    board.send_feature_report([9, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    print("script fired")
    print(board.get_manufacturer_string())
    board.close()

def main(args):
    bindkeys(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1].encode())
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the `SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw"` is too far removed from `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` to be able to use `ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}`, so, I just retooled the script to find the proper hidraw node itself and only fire it when the proper device is inserted:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import hid

def bindkeys(node):
    board = hid.device()
    board.open_path(node)
    board.send_feature_report([9, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    board.close()

def find_g710():
    for device in hid.enumerate():
        if device['vendor_id'] == 0x046d and device['product_id'] == 0xc24d and device['interface_number'] == 1:
            return device['path']

def main():
    g710 = find_g710()
    bindkeys(g710)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with the following udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c24d", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/g710.py"
```